# Can objects be shared between a thread and wx python and still keep data in sync?

Tags: python, multithreading, wxpython

im building a gui for [PyCaster](https://github.com/tinker1234/PyCaster/), and I need to take changes from the gui and apply to the socket thread. My understanding of threads is once started everything becomes local to that thread including object instances. The socket thread sleeps every 0.1 (assuming milliseconds) using `time.sleep`. The thread socket has events that fire and seen by the gui. Is there anyway to do the opposite of that? Meaning events fired that's seen by the thread that way I can pass data.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using something like Python's `Queue` synchronization primitive in order to pass information between multiple threads?

You would instantiate the `Queue` object in say your `main.py` file and then pass this instance of the queue to your multiple child-threads. Your GUI thread could then push new events to that `queue` instance whilst your second non-gui thread would constantly try to call `queue.get()` and then execute whatever it needs to execute when `queue.get()` is not None.

The official documentation for the `queue` class can be found here: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/queue.html and features a fairly decent example at the bottom!

I hope this helps!